# erro when I want to run an update on one of these app servers, I get:

Tags: gitlab

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

```
  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'songtrang97@DESKTOP-PTPE1UP.(none)')


Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository
```

Comment: You should read the FAQ, then formulate a question and use the gist of your question as title. It's not quite clear, what you're asking. My guess is you cannot push a commit/branch because the server/target has a policy requiring valid email adresses as part of the commit. If so, you'd have to amend your commit(s) once you've set a valid author/email (i.e. the same you used registering on that server (gitlab/github/gitea/whatever)). I could be wrong though. Maybe your client prevents you from committing without a valid author. Are you using the git cli?

Comment: In either case, you should read https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup - esp. the *Your Identity* part.